# logarithmic singularities in contour integration

Tags: logarithms, contour-integration, residue-calculus

How to evaluate the contour integral using the residue theorem if there is a logarithmic derivative? For example this:
$$\int_C \log\zeta(s)\frac{x^s}{s} ds$$
or even this:
$$ \int_C \frac{\log x}{x}dx$$
(I'm not interested in how to evaluate them, but in how the $\log$ affects them and/or how to evaluate integrals with logarithms)

Comment: The method used by Riemann is detailed in Edwards' [Riemann zeta function (p.$25$)](https://books.google.com/books?id=ruVmGFPwNhQC&pg=PA25).

Comment: Are there any papers on this method?

Comment: Well your first integral is (from my link) a [Mellin inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_inversion_theorem) of the logarithm of zeta which may help for a search... Concerning $\log$ integrals of simpler functions they may be handled using key hole contours with a branch cut in a specific direction as in this [example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098670) (the angle may be smaller than $2\pi$) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration#Example_.28V.29_.E2.80.93_the_square_of_the_logarithm).

Comment: Another method concerning your second integral is to observe that $\;-\dfrac d{ds} x^{-s}=\dfrac{\log(x)}{x^s}\;$ (with $s\to 1$  later) so that the second integral will be the derivative (under the integral sign) of $\;-\displaystyle \int \frac {dx}{x^s}$ as $s\to 1$ (more useful for real integrals since,  in $\mathbb{C}$, $x^{-s}$ is easier to handle for integer $s$ but...).

Comment: As I said, I am not interested in these integrals (except for the second one maybe). I know that the first integral is essentially the Riemann J function. I'm interested just in the methods used to solve these integrals.

Comment: I've heard something about the keyhole and branch cuts, but I don't know how to use them.