# How to calculate the integral $ I= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{a-1}}{t-x} dt$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

How to calculate the integral
$$ I= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{a-1}}{t-x} dt$$
using contour integration. ($x>0$ is fixed, $a \in \mathbb{R}$)

Approach: I calculated the values of $a$ for which the integral is convergent. The result was that $0<a<1$. We have two poles, at $t=0$ and $t=x$. I tried a circular key hole contour that excludes $t=0$ and $t=x$. The value of the integral integrated over the circular curves are zero I thougt. But the sum of the integrals integrated over the horizontal segments are $(1-e^{i(a-1)2\pi})I$, so the integral is zero. But I made a mistake I guess. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I tried to use the same keyhole in this other post: [Integration of $\ln $ around a keyhole contour](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098670/integration-of-ln-around-a-keyhole-contour?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: This integral must be computed in the Cauchy sense, otehrwise it is undefined because of the pole at $t=x$.

Comment: WA gives the result containing a hypergeometric function

Comment: @YvesDaoust But the pole $t=x$ is not in the contour. Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The pole is absolutely on the real axis. This integral must be computed in the Cauchy sense, otherwise it is undefined.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner What on earth are you thinking?  The answer can be found in closed form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the integrand is singular at $t=x$, this must be understood in the  Cauchy principal value sense.  Your contour should include little detours around $x=a$ as well as $0$.

[image]

The integrals over the arcs around $x$ are not $0$.  For the top part, I get $-i \pi x^{a-1}$; for the bottom part, $-i \pi x^{a-1} e^{2 \pi i (a-1)}$.

Comment: Oh yes indeed, I understand it! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using no contour integration we have:

We write $x=-|x|\leq 0$, $\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{t^{a-1}}{t-x}dt=\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{t^{a-1}}{|x|+t}dt$.

Set first $t=w|x|$. Then the integral becomes
$$
|x|^{a-1}\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{w^{a-1}}{1+w}dw
$$
Set now $w=\frac{y}{1-y}$. Hence the integral becomes
$$
|x|^{a-1}\int^{1}_{0}y^{a-1}(1-y)^{-a}dy=|x|^{a-1}\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(1-a)}{\Gamma(1)}=|x|^{a-1}\Gamma(a)\Gamma(1-a)
$$